# Django Graphql Auth not logged in user

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, graphql, django-graphql-jwt

I'm using Django Graphql Auth in my api but when I want to get the current logged in user always get the Anonymous.

```py
# settings.py

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # ...
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'base.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # 'graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend',
    'graphql_auth.backends.GraphQLAuthBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA_INDENT': 4,
    'SCHEMA': 'byt.schema.schema',
    'MIDDLEWARE': [
        'graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware',
        'graphene_django_extras.ExtraGraphQLDirectiveMiddleware'
    ]
}

GRAPHQL_AUTH = {
    'LOGIN_ALLOWED_FIELDS': ['email', 'username'],
    # ...
}
GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LONG_RUNNING_REFRESH_TOKEN': True,
    'ALLOW_LOGIN_NOT_VERIFIED': True,
    'JWT_ALLOW_ARGUMENT': True,
    "JWT_ALLOW_ANY_CLASSES": [
        "graphql_auth.mutations.Register",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.VerifyAccount",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.ResendActivationEmail",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.SendPasswordResetEmail",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.PasswordReset",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.ObtainJSONWebToken",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.VerifyToken",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.RefreshToken",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.RevokeToken",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.VerifySecondaryEmail",
    ],
}
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend'
```

```py
# custom user model 

class User(AbstractUser):
    ROLES = (
        ('ADMIN', 'ADMIN'),
        ('USER', 'USER'),
        ('BUSINESS', 'BUSINESS'),
        ('TALENT', 'TALENT')
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, default="John")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, default="Doe")
    email = models.EmailField(
        blank=False, max_length=254, verbose_name="email address")
    role = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=ROLES, default="USER")

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"  # e.g: "username", "email"
    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"  # e.g: "email", "primary_email"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

```py
# schema user
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from graphql_auth import mutations
from graphql_auth.schema import UserQuery, MeQuery


class AuthMutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    register = mutations.Register.Field()
    verify_account = mutations.VerifyAccount.Field()
    resend_activation_email = mutations.ResendActivationEmail.Field()
    send_password_reset_email = mutations.SendPasswordResetEmail.Field()
    password_reset = mutations.PasswordReset.Field()
    password_change = mutations.PasswordChange.Field()
    archive_account = mutations.ArchiveAccount.Field()
    delete_account = mutations.DeleteAccount.Field()
    update_account = mutations.UpdateAccount.Field()
    send_secondary_email_activation = mutations.SendSecondaryEmailActivation.Field()
    verify_secondary_email = mutations.VerifySecondaryEmail.Field()
    swap_emails = mutations.SwapEmails.Field()

    # django-graphql-jwt inheritances
    token_auth = mutations.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
    verify_token = mutations.VerifyToken.Field()
    refresh_token = mutations.RefreshToken.Field()
    revoke_token = mutations.RevokeToken.Field()


class Query(UserQuery, MeQuery, graphene.ObjectType):
    pass


class Mutation(AuthMutation, graphene.ObjectType):
    pass
```

The mutation tokenAuth returns a valid token but when I try to execute the 'me' query with that token in header the query returns null because info.context.user is the Anonymous.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you passing the bearer token? graphql_auth is using 'JWT' instead of 'Bearer' as token prefix.

Comment: Thanks when I used JWT token instead of Bearer my problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is JWT does not log in a user it only authenticate. ie, it only verifies that the username and password are valid.

So you cannot run the me query because of info.context.user, if you remove it will run.

To return a logged-in user, first have to log them in using:

```
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

    class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
        class Meta:
            model = YourUserModel

    class Query(ObjectType):
        ...
        me = graphene.Field(UserType)

        def resolve_me(self, info, **kwargs):
            username = kwargs.get('username')
            password = kwargs.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(user)
            if user.is_anonymous:
                raise Exception('Authentication Failure!')
            return YourUserModel.objects.get(pk=info.context.user)
```

NOTE: check the [DOC](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)